# Authenication error when accessing SharePoint Webservice using java

Tags: web-services, authentication

I am trying to access SharePoint UserGroup service using a Java client. I have generated the stubs from the WSDL using axis2-1.6.2 and using the following code to access the user group but getting following exception:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized

```
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setUsername(username);
auth.setPassword(password);
auth.setDomain(domain);
auth.setHost(host);
auth.setPort(80);

List authPrefs = new ArrayList(1);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
auth.setAuthSchemes(authPrefs);

UserGroupStub userGrp = new UserGroupStub("http://domainName/ProjectName/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx");

// Set authenticator
            userGrp._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
            userGrp._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
userGrp._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(10000);
// Get request and execute
GetUserCollectionFromGroup req = new GetUserCollectionFromGroup();
req.setGroupName(grpName);
GetUserCollectionFromGroupResponse res = userGrp.getUserCollectionFromGroup(req);
```

Comment: Please check in the IIS Log which http error code is emitted. 401.1, 401.2, etc. have different meaning and solutions. You have to find the status and substatus in the log (or does the java client is telling it)? [Norbert's answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/40361/3497) is probably the correct one. The substatus will help ton confirm (or not!) it. Also, you should give us a bit of more details, which version of sharepoint and windows are your running ?

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2010 and XP SP3. I see the following log:                                                     2012/07/07 20:06:41:442 IST [DEBUG] header - << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
2012/07/07 20:06:41:442 IST [DEBUG] header - << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2012/07/07 20:06:41:442 IST [DEBUG] header - << "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5[\r][\n]"
2012/07/07 20:06:41:442 IST [DEBUG] header - << "SPRequestGuid: 15c6411c-1b6e-4e30-a894-40333daa1241[\r][\n]"
2012/07/07 20:06:41:442 IST [DEBUG] header - << "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"

Comment: this is not a iis log, and you don't us which version of windows on *server side* you are running. By default IIS logs are located in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

Comment: I have not been able to get details of the version & IIS logs. The logs that I sent are full wire logs from the httpclient.

Comment: If you notice the first handshake returns HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized and WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate; WWW-Authenticate: NTLM;  but able to figure how to make subsequent req. Looks like its  not a one step process.                                                          1: C  --> S   GET ...
2: C <--  S   401 Unauthorized    WWW-Authenticate: NTLM  
3: C  --> S   GET ...Authorization: NTLM <>
4: C <--  S   401 Unauthorized WWW-Authenticate: NTLM <>    
5: C  --> S   GET ...Authorization: NTLM <>                6: C <--  S   200 Ok

Comment: Have you solve your problem? I meet the same problem with you and could you tell me how to solve the problem ? Thanks Dekui

Answer (score 1):

If the Java Client is running on a different server than the Sharepoint Webservice (and I think this is probably the case) and the AD account, under which your client process runs, is different from the account you use to authenticate with on the webservice, then I think you have a double-hop issue, due to the fact that you are trying to use NTLM.

NTLM is not able to delegate user credentials, which would be required in the following scenario: Process **A** is trying to access Service **B** but with the credentials of User **C**. This means that **A** should be able to delegate **C**'s credentials to **B**, but because of NTLM, it cannot.
In order to delegate user credentials, you should use Kerberos instead of NTLM. But be aware, that Kerberos is more difficult to configure and set up.

A more detailed explanation on the difference between NTLM and Kerberos, you can find here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx

Comment: Yes. java client is running on a different server that sharepoint. But, my AD account where the client process is running is the same credentials that i am using to authenticate my service. The same service is getting called successfully using .NET client:

Answer (score 1):

If you extend your web application in Sharepoint Central Admin and set the extended web application as anonymous access, then set anonymous access on your web application or site you will avoid the authentication 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried activating the “basic authentication” for your SharePoint site in the IIS settings of your server?

It is also worth a try, if you change anonymous access to the root wsdl on your SharePoint server to open the service port.